# ArangoDB Foxx application vs native client

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, arangodb, nosql

I wonder what your thoughts on whether develop your customized Foxx application which will hold all logic and access it via HTTP API or use native ArangoDB client and build everything on desired platform completely.

i.e. you can use .Net arangodb client and use its API or build a FOXX app and use it directly via HTTP.

Comment: beside [foxx](https://www.arangodb.com/foxx/) performance advantages(reducing network request, no cost of .net object serialization, ...), i think it is more about your application architecture, you can have microservices at .net but you should base your decision on how things like maintenance, security, scaling out are done in both solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of the reason, why we're swapping the term from Foxx-'application' to Foxx-'service' - it obeys the [Microservice definition](https://docs.arangodb.com/Foxx/index.html).

Its not exclusiv or - as in you don't have to decide against or for Foxx and a native application.
Generally you would rather implement business logic inside of the client that may also use AQL.

In Foxx one would rather locate data centric tasks like:

- enhanced access controls
- aggregate over several collections
- reduce the result set to transfer to the client
- group several queries to one transaction
- as raoof hojat already pointed out its a good thing if you i.e. want to save network bandwith.
- Foxx can work on Data before its serialized and transfered over the network

which may give you performance advantages over doing that in the client instead of inside the database.

Comment: these were exactly my thoughts originally. in case you extensive data-centric queries using Foxx service may help you to save round trips to server plus gives you performance benefits executing on the server. thanks Raoof and @dothebart for your replies.